# Dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled when trying to run elastic service within a docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.4.4 in my rails app. To start it locally I download elastic [from there](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-4-4), unpack, add

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

to `elasticsearch-1.4.4/config/elasticsearch.yml` and run `elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin/elasticsearch`

**Tests pass with no errors.** When I try to start elasticsearch service as a docker container I do the following steps:

Add `Dockerfile.elasticsearch-1.4.4`:

```
FROM elasticsearch:1.4.4

RUN echo 'script.inline: on' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RUN echo 'script.indexed: on' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

Build the image:

```
docker build - < Dockerfile.elasticsearch-1.4.4 -t hirurg103/elasticsearch-1.4.4:1.0
```

Start the container:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 "hirurg103/elasticsearch-1.4.4:1.0"
```

When I run tests **some of them fail with**:

```
nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled
```

I tried to build elasticsearch `1.6.1` and `2.0.0` with docker, but the error remains the same

How can I change Dockerfile so it will allow to execute scripts for the elasticsearch service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile a docker image with elasticsearch with scripting enabled from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:1.4.4

...

RUN echo 'script.inline: on' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RUN echo 'script.indexed: on' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RUN echo 'script.disable_dynamic: false' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
...
CMD ["elasticsearch", "-Des.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml"]
# Note this line! ^
```

Seems like that elasticsearch was ignoring the config file `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` for some reason, not sure why. If you have any ideas, could you please share them in the comments